# How to add custom menu in Microsoft Lync 64 bit (Lync/Skype for business)

Tags: registry, lync, lync-2013, skype-for-business

I went through [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945535.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and added all registry setting for adding a custom menu in Lync and its also works, But it works only in 32 bit of Lync. so could you please tell me how would I add a custom menu in my Lync 64 bit (Lync/ Skype for Business).
Here I am not talking about OS version its 64 bit of Skype UI.

Comment: On a 64 Bit OS just use the registry key location described for the 32 Bit OS (without the `Wow6432Node` sub-folder). This is where the 64 Bit software on a 64 Bit OS is configured.

Comment: @Filburt, Thanks, but I am not talking about OS version, what I am asking is how to add menu in Lync 64 bit?

Comment: @Filburt is correct, it should be the same as the 32bit OS registry key path.  64bit app means 64bit OS so the path is a native path not the redirected path (Wow6432Node).

Comment: This is my registry setting for 32bit of Lync
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync\SessionManager\Apps\{00024512-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
"Name"="Run App"
"ApplicationInstallPath"="LyncMenuCommand.exe"
"path"="\"path\LyncMenuCommand.exe\" %contact-id%"
"ExtensibleMenu"="MainWindowRightClick;ConversationWindowActions;ConversationWindowRightClick;ContactCardMenu"
"ApplicationType"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"SessionType"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

Comment: And here is for 64bit of Lync
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync\SessionManager\Apps\{00024512-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
"Name"="Run App"
"ApplicationInstallPath"="LyncMenuCommand.exe"
"path"="\"path\LyncMenuCommand.exe\" %contact-id%"
"ExtensibleMenu"="MainWindowRightClick;ConversationWindowActions;ConversationWindowRightClick;ContactCardMenu"
"ApplicationType"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"SessionType"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

Comment: Still menu is not appearing in Lync, This setting is working with 32bit of Lync in any version of OS(32bit and 64bit), But not working in 64bit of Lync in any OS version(32bit or 64bit).